# Change in temperature between pressed objects

Tags: pressure, temperature

Will there be a change in temperature at the surface of contact between two bodies if they are pressed against each another with a pressure of 50psi for a period of 12 hours? If yes then how much above room temperature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Simply having two bodies exert forces on each other is not going to cause a change in temperature.  If there is no motion the forces do no work.  Consider a pile of rocks.  I's sure you could find a pair of rocks with a pressure of 50 psi between them, maybe it's been that way for many years, that's not going to heat anything up.